# errors installing pip on Mac OS X

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install pip on a Mac OS X system using python version 2.6 and got the following errors.

```
$ python /tmp/get-pip.py 
/tmp/tmpzyN3Si/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Collecting pip
/tmp/tmpzyN3Si/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 280, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 439, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 244, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 810, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 920, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 36, in send
    cached_response = self.controller.cached_request(request)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 102, in cached_request
    resp = self.serializer.loads(request, self.cache.get(cache_url))
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 108, in loads
    return getattr(self, "_loads_v{0}".format(ver))(request, data)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 184, in _loads_v2
    return self.prepare_response(request, cached)
  File "/tmp/tmpLZAZtY/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 145, in prepare_response
    **cached["response"]
TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Then I tried it with python2.6:

```
python2.6 /tmp/get-pip.py
/tmp/tmpI57ALq/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip
/tmp/tmpI57ALq/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  Downloading pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |################################| 1.1MB 303kB/s 
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-18.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462kB)
    100% |################################| 462kB 723kB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63kB)
    100% |################################| 65kB 3.6MB/s 
Collecting argparse (from wheel)
  Downloading argparse-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, argparse, wheel
Successfully installed argparse-1.3.0 pip-7.1.2 setuptools-18.3.1 wheel-0.24.0
```

But pip command can't be found when I try to use it.

```
$  which pip
pip not found
```

When I run python2.6 again, I get the following:

```
python2.6 /tmp/get-pip.py
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/tmp/tmpCu8MaZ/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

I've read that **pip install requests[security]** would solve the problem but first I need to install pip in order to install those packages.

**EDIT**:
It seems like this is a bug related to the Python 2.6.1.
I have installed a newer version of Python (2.7.10) with Homebrew and installed pip using easy_install. Then I added path /usr/local/bin to have a priority and pip installs packages now. I'm not sure if it's ok to use non-native python for pip though.

Comment: Have you already tried `python -m pip install requests[security]`?

Comment: @cel I've just tried it and it returns `no matches found: requests[security]`

Comment: the error was due to zsh syntax, and I managed to install pip and with `pip install 'requests[security]'` it still returns InsecurePlatformWarning...

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `easy_install`?

Here's an **EASY** solution.

First of all, make sure you have `Python` installed. How? Open terminal and run the following command.

```
python --version
```

If this command returns a version number that means python is already installed. That also means you already have access to `easy_install` considering you are using `OS X`.

Now, all you have to do is run the following command.

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

After that, `pip` will be installed and you'll be able to use it for installing other packages.

Cheers!
Let me know if this way of installing pip worked for you.

Comment: Worked on mac os 10.12.3 when instructions found elsewhere did not.

Answer (score 0):

Re Install Python And then it will work . Pip comes pre-installed when you install Python on your system .